# What is the meaning of starting a goroutine from another goroutine?

Tags: go

From [this file](https://github.com/fhmq/hmq/blob/master/pool/fixpool.go), I do not understand why the function startWorker is written like the following.:

```
func (p *WorkerPool) dispatch() {
    for i := 0; i < p.maxWorkers; i++ {
        p.taskQueue[i] = make(chan func())
        go startWorker(p.taskQueue[i])
    }
}
```

```golang
func startWorker(taskChan chan func()) {
    go func() {
        var task func()
        var ok bool
        for {
            task, ok = <-taskChan
            if !ok {
                break
            }
            // Execute the task.
            task()
        }
    }()
}
```

If I were the developer, I will write this function like this:

```golang
func startWorker(taskChan chan func()) {
    var task func()
    var ok bool
    for {
        task, ok = <-taskChan
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        // Execute the task.
        task()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should re-indent your code first

Comment: Given that `startWorker` is only called from a go statement, there's no need for `startWorker` to also start a goroutine.

Comment: `go func`  is use to excute to do the similar work at same time. It make the running time of programs fast er.

Comment: @Anshu: No, it doesn't make running time fast. If anything, it makes running time slower. What it does is run things concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Go Best Practices](https://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#25) by Francesc Campoy Flores your statement is correct. It is redundant to start a goroutine which also starts another.

```golang
func (p *WorkerPool) dispatch() {
    for i := 0; i < p.maxWorkers; i++ {
        p.taskQueue[i] = make(chan func())
        go startWorker(p.taskQueue[i])
    }
}
```

This is how it's been used in the library. Removing go routine in startWorker makes sense.

Also as Peter mentioned here it is also ok to change the `go startWorker()` line to `startWorker()`.

Comment: Conventionally, methods named Start or StartX don't block. See [exec.Cmd.Start](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start) or [httptest.Server.Start](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server.Start), for instance. I would rather remove the go statement at the call site.

Comment: since this is an internal usage it's also fine. There is no right or wrong way I guess. It's how we structure our code